# CustomEditText AppCombat tinting

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-appcompat, android-styles

I have a `CustomEditText`, because i want to apply a font inside the `CustomView`. But also iwant to change the color of the underline with the new Appcombat style attributes `colorControlNormal` , ....
unfortunately the color changes doesn't work for the CustomEditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget tinting is not fully supported for some scenarios, yours included:

> Q: Why is my EditText (or other widget listed above) not being tinted correctly on my pre-Lollipop device?
>
> A: The widget tinting in appcompat works by intercepting any layout inflation and inserting a special tint-aware version of the widget in its place. For most people this will work fine but I can think of a few scenarios where this won’t work including:
>
> - You have your own custom version of the widget (i.e. you’ve extended EditText)
> - ...
>
> The special tint aware widgets are currently hidden because they’re an unfinished implementation detail.

Source: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#faq